# Could not create the index.html file - TimThumb

Tags: php, timthumb

I am using TimThumb version : 2.8.14.

After moving site on UAT server its stopped working.

It's show following error.

> Could not create the index.html file - to fix this create an empty
>   file named index.html file in the cache directory. Could not create
>   cache clean timestamp file.

I have tried some solutions like folder permission and all but still not luck. Issue still coming.

Is this issue from server side ?

Answer (score 0):

Look in your timthumb-config.php, to check if the FILE_CACHE_DIRECTORY is set to the directory you think it is.

You could also delete the existing index.html file that's in the tim thumb cache directory, as tim thumb will automatically create it

You may also need to check the config file to see if the MEMORY_LIMIT is set high enough for your particular images.

[Timthumb can't show image after it's uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396991/timthumb-cant-show-image-after-its-uploaded)

Comment: I have checked all of above points, its all as per requirement but still i am facing same error. any other solution for this ?